# Let $f, g$ be functions continuous on $[a, \infty)$ also let $f(a)≤g(a)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ How to show that if $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>a$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f, g$ be functions continuous and differentiable on $[a, \infty)$ also let $f(a)≤g(a)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ How to show that if $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x>a$?

I would like to know if this statement is true. It's intuitive, but I couldn't demonstrate it. It is intended to be a method that helps us to know if one function is greater than another from a certain number.

Comment: Write the whole thing in terms of $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$. You should be able to answer the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$. Then $h'(x)>0$ if $x>a$, and therefore, by the Mean Value Theorem, if $x>a$, $h(x)=h(x)-h(a)>0$.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind. I just typed up notes with an example along these lines for my students for MVT tomorrow.